# How to add videos to a storyboard page (Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, video

I was woking on a small app project, and I made a video to put into the storyboard. My only problem, however, is that I don't know how to add the video to the storyboard. The ImageView doesn't accept the filetype (.mov). Online, I have only found a tutorial for Xcode 4, and nothing else. I need the video and not a GIF file because I don't want the GIF to loop forever. I'm using Swift.

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to do it in code, create MPMoviePlayer and add it's layer to your view.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, would it be easier to create a GIF, and if so, how could I set the GIF to stop after a certain amount of time (say, 60 mins)? The video is only 3 frames that repeat themselves for an hour, so it would probably work better in a .GIF format.

Comment: Well if it is just 3 frame it would be overkill to use a movie, since it will increase the size of you app. But animated GIFs are not support un the UIImageView by default. You can however pass 3 images to the UIImageView which it will animate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to add the `MediaPlayer.framework`  under the build phase option

Build phase -> link binary with library -> use the add button and type mediaplayer and add the `MediaPlayer.framework`. Once done add the following code:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType:"mp4")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = self.moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
            player.view.sizeToFit()
            player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.Fill
            player.fullscreen = true
            player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
            player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
            player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
            player.play()
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Important : The `MPMoviePlayerViewController` class is formally deprecated in iOS 9. To play video content, use the `AVPictureInPictureController` or `AVPlayerViewController` class from the AVKit framework, or the `WKWebView` class from WebKit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you want the video auto play or not. If you want an auto play video you can add a video using Mediaplayer. I past for you my code. I am just a beginner in swift, but it is working for me.

First add the video to your project

and then in your code your can do like that:

```
import MediaPlayer

class YOURCLASS: UIViewController {

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        playVideo()
    }

    var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerController?

    func playVideo() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("THENAMEOFYOURVIDEO", ofType:"m4v")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

        if let player = moviePlayer {

 player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 300)

            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            player.controlStyle = .None 
            player.shouldAutoplay = true
            player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One  
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)

        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me, however, the build fails due to an issue with the width on line 20, and when I try to change the dimensions to fix the video appropriately, it fails to build.

Comment: Sorry I did not paste correctly my code: player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 300)

Comment: Important : The `MPMoviePlayerViewController` class is formally deprecated in iOS 9. To play video content, use the `AVPictureInPictureController` or `AVPlayerViewController` class from the AVKit framework, or the `WKWebView` class from WebKit.